# Difficulty in installing the Yoti Doc Scan iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using the Yoti Doc Scan iOS SDK in my iOS application and unfortunately, it's not working as expected so hereby in this email, I'll mention the steps that I've followed and the issues which I've faced so far.

I've followed this site for implementation - https://github.com/getyoti/yoti-doc-scan-ios

Steps of implementation

For install lfs and Carthage, I've run these commands in terminal
brew install git-lfs
git lfs install
git lfs install --system
carthage update --no-use-binaries
Now, as mentioned, I needed to follow the below step,

Note: This will fetch dependencies into a Carthage/Checkouts folder, then copy YotiDocScan.framework and ScanDocument.framework into a Carthage/Build/iOS folder. Please find Microblink.framework and Microblink.bundle in the Carthage/Checkouts/blinkid-ios folder.

But the problem is I couldn't find these frameworks in Carthage/Checkouts folder. From where I supposed to copy this framework? But somehow I did get the framework by installing this Carthage in another PC by happy coding and but in that case, also I couldn't find these frameworks in Carthage/Checkouts folder. I get it directly in the Carthage/Build/iOS folder. and As it wasn't coming in my Xcode framework folder, I simply just drag and drop that frameworks from Carthage/Build/iOS to my project path.

I'm using Xcode 11 for this project.

Hereby I'm sending you some of my screenshots so that you can check the implementation setting for the YOTI doc scan.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I was getting IPA processing failed error while archiving the build so I did this change which you can see in the image that uncheck the rebuild from Bitcode option and then click on next fast. Hope because of these change app store won't reject our application.

Now even though I couldn't follow the installation step as instructed, I did manage to do library relevant code in my project. But again for every request, I'm only getting code - 5004 error which I can't find why I'm facing.
 
Please let me know where I've gone wrong.

Thank you in advance.